# Transactional in Java Spring

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc

When using Java Annotation, I just need to declare bean:

```
public HibernateTransactionManager transactionManagement
(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
    HibernateTransactionManager tx = new HibernateTransactionManager
            (sessionFactory);
    return tx;
}
```

And then give @Transactional above method.
But with XML configuration, I did :

```
<bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"></property>
</bean>
<bean id="countryDAOImp" class="src.com.model.CountryDAOImp">
</bean>
<tx:annotation-driven proxy-target-class="true" />
```

And this error happen: `NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/engine/transaction/spi/TransactionContext`

did I miss something? :D
Thank you!

Comment: Is [`hibernate-core`](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-core) in your classpath?

Comment: I'm using maven, I did add hibernate-core into pom file :)

Comment: Could you show us the whole stack trace? If you use eclipse check if this package and class are in maven dependencies. Then check if they are in target folder... something like target/${projectName}/WEB-INF/lib

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue is related to your spring hibernate compatibility.

Check your spring dependency version and hibernate version compatibility.You are using `org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager`.You must be using hibernate 4.x version of dependency.

Try this combination **4.1.0.Final with spring 3.1.1.RELEASE**.It should work.